# Why does the images in show sometimes and doesn't other times?

Tags: javascript

I have a blog and for this blog there are summary post that contain the first image in each post. In order to try and keep the summary images to a good size so I had to resize them with javascript. The problem is after resizing them, the images only show up sometimes. In many cases I have to reload the window a few times before the images show up in the summary post. I don't understand what's causing this. 
Blog: http://kingarthur13th.blogspot.com/

Here's the javascript:

```
function createSummaryAndThumb(pID){
   var div = document.getElementById(pID);
   var imgtag = "";
   var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");


   var img_thumb_width;
   var img_thumb_height;

   var summ = summary_noimg;
   if(img.length>=1) {  

        img_thumb_width  = Math.round(img[0].naturalWidth  * 0.6);
        img_thumb_height = Math.round(img[0].naturalHeight * 0.6);

        imgtag = '<span style="float:left; padding:0px 10px 5px 0px;"><img  src="'+img[0].src+'" width="'+img_thumb_width+'px" height="'+img_thumb_height+'px" style=" padding:5px;border:1px solid #222;"/></span>';
        summ = summary_img;
    }

    var summary = imgtag + '<div>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ) + '</div>';
    div.innerHTML = summary;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked to see that the images are actually downloading?  If they're downloading, but not showing up, it's a problem with your markup/styles/scripting.  If they're not downloading at all, then there's probably an issue with the way you're dynamically loading the file path of the images.

Comment: The images are downloading but they're not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the images are downloading just fine, but they're not showing up because the value for their width and height returned by your script is 0.

You could troubleshoot your script to figure out why the values aren't returning the natural dimensions * 0.6 (It seems to me like your script should work - IDK what's happening there), or you could just specify a width and set height to auto like this:

```
<span style="float:left; padding:0px 10px 5px 0px;"><img  src="'+img[0].src+'" width="100px" height="auto" style=" padding:5px;border:1px solid #222;"/></span>'
```

Or better yet, create a CSS class that specifies max-width and height auto like this:

```
.blog-thumbnail { max-width: 100px; height: auto; }
```

I would suggest choosing one of these two options for two reasons:

1. You still accomplish your goal of preserving your images' proportions.
2. Your design will be cleaner, because all of your images will be the same width.

Comment: Thank you so much. Lol, now I feel stupid for not even thinking about Overflow:hidden;. The pictures show up every time now and I no longer need to keep reloading the page.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to try

Check the values you are getting from `img_thumb_width` and `img_thumb_height`.  You should be using integer values, you may be getting a floating point number.

Also, maybe the images are downloading, but it is just taking time to show up.